# html5 time validation issue using pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am using the HTML5 in build validation but for Time, i am sing the following code 
The code is pretty simple as it is just checking the format of the time, i am not sure what i am doing wrong here

```
<input name="taskStartTime" type="text" value="05:15 PM" placeholder="Enter a valid start time." size="10" pattern="/^\d{1,2}:\d{2}([ap]m)?$/" title="Enter Valid Time">
```

But it is not validating and it says invalid time, i think my regex is right, but not sure what is going on here...

Comment: Your regex does not allow for a space before the "am/pm" string. Also, in `pattern` attributes, `^` and `$` are implied and therefore not needed.

Comment: .. and some upper and lower case consistency for am/pm is required. More generally when a regex isn't working, try to break it down into smaller/simpler parts and test those independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the forward slashes: they are part of JavaScript regex literal syntax, not part of general regex syntax. You don't really need the `^` and `$` either because for an input element pattern they are implied.

The value you are setting in your example, `05:15 PM` won't match your regex either, because it has a space in it and because the "PM" is in capitals. To allow for that:

```
pattern="\d{1,2}:\d{2}( ?[apAP][mM])?"
```

Note that for html5 input `pattern` attributes you can't set the `i` case insensitive flag that JavaScript (and some other regex implementations) allow. According to the specification it does use the JS syntax for the pattern itself, but *"it is compiled "with the global, ignoreCase, and multiline flags disabled".*

Comment: and how can we apply regex flags, like `/[ap][m]/i`?

Comment: @vp_arth - You can't (as far as I know). I'll update my answer to say so.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<input name="taskStartTime" type="text" value="05:15 PM" placeholder="Enter a valid start time." size="10" pattern="^\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s([AP]M)?$" title="Enter Valid Time">
```